# Android Web Browser with Auto Refresh Ideal for Set and Forget

Tags: android, web-browser

I have been racking my brain trying to find an ideal web browser for a setup we have on an Android box. Basically it sits on the same web page, and refreshes every 15 or so seconds. However, every now and again there is a dramatic spike on the web page, and as a result, we lose connection. This is where things get tricky; I can not find a browser that fully supports the ability to simply reconnect to the page on the next refresh, and be fully capable of being left to resolve the temporary down time on its own.

We started with Chrome, but could not get automatic refreshing. The web page supports it, but naturally, no web page, no refreshing. I have tried FullScreen browsing (ideally we would like the feature of going full screen), but when the site initially fails to connect, we get a big popup notification to let us know. We don't want to have to close the popup every time this happens. We have also used Yandex and Dolphin, but both appear to stop refreshing as soon as the website fails to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ultimately went for Yandex, due to time constraints. I was able to manually modify other aspects to accommodate for the shortcomings of the browser, itself.